# Show an String XML data on a view without parsing

Tags: android, android-view, android-parser

I have a String like this:

```
 <p><span class="qlst">     <span class="caption">QuickLinks</span>
<ul>
    <li><a href="./journal/molecules/about#aims">Aims</a></li>
    <li><a href="./journal/molecules/about#scope">Scope</a></li>
    <li><a href="./journal/molecules/about#indexing">Indexing &amp; Abstracting</a></li>
</ul>
</span></p>
<p><i>Molecules</i> (ISSN 1420-3049, CODEN: MOLEFW) is an open access journal of synthetic organic chemistry and natural product chemistry. All articles are peer-reviewed and published continously upon acceptance. <i>Molecules</i> is published by MDPI, Basel, Switzerland.</p>
<h2><a name="aims"></a>Aims</h2>
<p>Our aim is to encourage chemists to publish as much as possible their experimental detail, particularly synthetic procedures and characterization information. There is no restriction on the length of the experimental section. In addition, availability of compound samples is published and considered as important information. Authors are encouraged to register or deposit their chemical samples through the non-profit international organization <a href="http://www.mdpi.org/" target="_blank">Molecular Diversity Preservation International (MDPI)</a>.</p>
<p>Molecules has been launched in 1996 to preserve and exploit molecular diversity of both, chemical information and chemical substances.</p>
<h2><a name="scope"></a>Scope</h2>
<p>Subject areas include:</p>
<ul>
    <li>compound preparation (synthesis, biosynthesis, extraction, etc.)</li>
    <li>structural elucidation (X-ray crystallography, NMR, etc.)</li>
    <li>chemical and biological activities</li>
    <li>applications as functional materials, additives, catalysts, etc.</li>
    <li>combinatorial synthesis and parallel synthesis</li>
    <li>engineering and robotics of multi-step synthesis</li>
    <li>applications of compound collections (such as high throughput screening) and combinatorial compound libraries</li>
    <li>molecular diversity assessments</li>
    <li>compound archives management</li>
    <li>compound database design and management</li>
</ul>
<h2><a name="indexing"></a>Indexing &amp; Abstracting</h2>
<p>See <a href="/journal/molecules/indexing">Indexing &amp; Abstracting<br />
</a></p>
<h2>Book Reviews</h2>
<p>Authors and publishers are encouraged to send review copies of their recent related books to Dr. Shu-Kun Lin, MDPI Center, Kandererstrasse 25, CH-4057 Basel, Switzerland. Received books will be listed first as &quot;Books Received&quot;, then offered to the scholarly community for preparing reviews.</p>
<h2>Announcement and Advertisement</h2>
<p>Announcements regarding academic activities such as conferences are published for free. Advertisement can be either published or placed on the pertinent website. Contact e-mail address is <a href="javascript:location.href='mailto:'+String.fromCharCode(109,111,108,101,99,117,108,101,115,64,109,100,112,105,46,99,111,109)+'?'">molecules@mdpi.com</a>.</p>
```

Is it possible to show this string directly in a view (like text view or something else) with an automatic style (as for exemple a browswer can do) ?

If yes, how to do this, is there a special view for? 
If no, i have to parse this, right?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd think that "automatic styling" would require parsing on some level...

Comment: There is a automatic styling for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TextView to show the xml content as it is :

```
 TextView textDisplayed =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); textDisplayed.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); 
textDisplayed.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContent));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Deva, i have to set the textView resource in the xml or?

Comment: Edited my answer forgot to add the setText method.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("YOUR TEXT"));
```